# UIkit align the spinner to the center

Tags: html, css, user-experience, getuikit

I'm trying to align [UIKit](https://getuikit.com/)'s (3.0.0) spinner to the center of the page. But it won't.

I have tried applying [align](https://getuikit.com/docs/align) to it directly and wrapping it in container like this but nothing works:

```
<div class="uk-inline uk-margin">
 <div class="uk-position-center">
   <div uk-spinner></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

https://getuikit.com/docs/spinner

Comment: try ` <div class="uk-position-center">
   <div uk-spinner></div>
 </div>`
only

Comment: Yeah that works. Thanks! Wanna put it as an answer? I'll accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this only.

```
<div class="uk-position-center">
  <div uk-spinner></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to center itself center of the screen, not the containing div.